# Django: For Loop to Iterate Form Fields

Tags: django, forms, loops, field

I don't want to use django's built in form generation, seeking to specify each field in my template in order to customize the html output.

How do I iterate over a series of form fields?

If my form looks like this:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    main_image = forms.ImageField()
    second_image = forms.ImageField()
    third_image = forms.ImageField()
    fourth_image = forms.ImageField()
    ...
```

Is there way to write a `{% for %}` loop so that I can iterate through:

```
{{ form.main_image }}
{{ form.second_image }}
{{ form.third_image }}
{{ form.fourth_image }}
```

I tried the following which seemed logical, but did not work:

```
{% for field in form %}
  {{ form.field }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Well this would clearly not work:

```
{% for field in form %}
    {{ form.field }}
{% endfor %}
```

but this will:

```
{% for field in form %}
    {{ field }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: What if I wanted to exclude the first field and only show the last fields?

Comment: @NickB the dirty way: `{% if forloop.counter != 1 %}`, but I think you're better of, by just excluding the field in form definition..

Comment: It's nice to point out (for beginners like myself) that this code alone won't display field names, but only text boxes and widgets(for file fields), all side by side. Maybe try <p>{{ field.name | title }}{{ field }}</p>

Answer (score 18):

The best way is to use two loops, one for hidden fields and one for visible fields :

visibles:

```
{% for field in form.visible_fields %}
    {{ field.label }}
    {{ field }}
{% endfor %}
```

hiddens:

```
{% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
    {{ hidden }}
{% endfor %}
```

in this way you will have better control over UI elements.

Answer (score 7):

This one should work :

```
{% for field in form %}
  {{ field }}
{% endfor %}
```

Once you loop through **field in form** , you can't access form.field

Comment: Yes thank you! But I apologize that @mariodev answered the question first. But have a +1 as appreciation!

Comment: I don't care about the credit , i'm just happy that you've overcame this issue :)

Comment: Haha, thanks! Any ideas about how to exclude the first field and only show the remaining fields?

Comment: I'll give you a clue : it's all about a flow control

Answer (score 4):

For any frontend developers looking to customize a Django form you can use a package called `django-widget-tweaks` to render fields individually. Example code below:

```
{# Your template with the form #}
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load widget_tweaks %}

<form action="" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}

    {% for field in form %}
        <label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}">
          {{ field.label }}{% if field.field.required %}*{% endif %}
        </label>
        {% render_field field %}
    {% endfor %}

    <button type="button">
        Submit Form
    </button>
</form>
```

**Note:** You'll want to make this look nicer of course, and you may want to loop through your form errors if there are any.

[They have some very useful examples](https://pypi.org/project/django-widget-tweaks/) on their PyPi page as well.